# Add a value as a new row to a dataframe but keep all other columns NA

Tags: r, row, data-manipulation

Here is my sample dataset:

```
mydata = data.frame (ID =c(1,2,3,4,5),
subject = c("His","Geo","Geo","His","Geo"),
age = c(21,24,26,23,26))
```

I would like to add a row at the top. I would like it to say "School 1" in the ID column while all other columns remain blank. The following is what I am looking for:

```
mydata = data.frame (ID =c("School 1",1,2,3,4,5),
subject = c(NA,"His","Geo","Geo","His","Geo"),
age = c(NA,21,24,26,23,26))
```

I have tried the following, but it ends up populating the value across all columns:

```
mydata <- rbind(c("School 1"), mydata)
```

I know the following code will get me what I want, but I would like to avoid having to list out NA's as my dataset has tons of columns

```
mydata <- rbind(c("School 1", NA,NA), mydata)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, based on `dplyr`. We first need to convert `ID` from `numeric` to `character`.

```r
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  mutate(ID = as.character(ID)) %>% 
  bind_rows(list(ID = "School 1"), .)

#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   ID       subject   age
#>   <chr>    <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 School 1 <NA>       NA
#> 2 1        His        21
#> 3 2        Geo        24
#> 4 3        Geo        26
#> 5 4        His        23
#> 6 5        Geo        26
```

Comment: This works great, thanks so much! Can I ask what does the period at the end do?

Comment: The `.` is the output of the last instruction in the pipe, that is: `mutate(ID = as.character(ID))`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `` `length<-` ``, which fills up non existing elements with `NA` up to a specified total length you may create a vector with length exactly to `ncol(mydata)`, with the first element `'School 1'`, then `rbind`.

```
rbind(`length<-`("School 1", ncol(mydata)), mydata)
#         ID subject age
# 1 School 1    <NA>  NA
# 2        1     His  21
# 3        2     Geo  24
# 4        3     Geo  26
# 5        4     His  23
# 6        5     Geo  26
```

### Explanation

Maybe it is worth thinking about the concept of a data frame to be able to better understand OP's problem. Actually it's a modified `list`,

```
typeof(mydata)
# [1] "list"
```

and consists of vectors as elements with equal lengths, which we can see when we `unclass` it.

```
unclass(mydata)
# $ID
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $subject
# [1] "His" "Geo" "Geo" "His" "Geo"
# 
# $age
# [1] 21 24 26 23 26
# 
# attr(,"row.names")
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

We may easily add other elements to a list,

```
c(mydata, foo='something')
# $ID
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $subject
# [1] "His" "Geo" "Geo" "His" "Geo"
# 
# $age
# [1] 21 24 26 23 26
# 
# $foo
# [1] "something"
```

but making a data frame out of it, the values are getting [recycled](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Vector-arithmetic), if nothing else is provided (which is actually very useful).

```
as.data.frame(c(mydata, foo='something'))
#   ID subject age       foo
# 1  1     His  21 something
# 2  2     Geo  24 something
# 3  3     Geo  26 something
# 4  4     His  23 something
# 5  5     Geo  26 something
```

This is exactly the same with `cbind`.

```
cbind(mydata, foo='something')
#   ID subject age       foo
# 1  1     His  21 something
# 2  2     Geo  24 something
# 3  3     Geo  26 something
# 4  4     His  23 something
# 5  5     Geo  26 something
```

If we provide a vector of appropriate length (i.e. a **column** to the data frame), R has no reason to recycle.

```
as.data.frame(c(mydata, list(foo=c('something', rep(NA, 4)))))
#   ID subject age       foo
# 1  1     His  21 something
# 2  2     Geo  24      <NA>
# 3  3     Geo  26      <NA>
# 4  4     His  23      <NA>
# 5  5     Geo  26      <NA>

cbind(mydata, foo=c('something', rep(NA, 4)))
#   ID subject age       foo
# 1  1     His  21 something
# 2  2     Geo  24      <NA>
# 3  3     Geo  26      <NA>
# 4  4     His  23      <NA>
# 5  5     Geo  26      <NA>
```

Adding **rows** is slightly different. As we easily may see in the `unclass`ed data frame above, we may imagine, that we need to `append` something to each single vector at the desired position. It goes against the grain, so to speak. Obviously this is also computational more expensive, and thus much slower.

```
as.data.frame(Map(append, mydata, values=c('something', rep(NA, 2)), after=0))
#          ID subject  age
# 1 something    <NA> <NA>
# 2         1     His   21
# 3         2     Geo   24
# 4         3     Geo   26
# 5         4     His   23
# 6         5     Geo   26
```

Notice, that to append a shorter vector than `ncol` will also result in recycling as experienced by OP.

```
as.data.frame(Map(append, mydata, values='something', after=0))
#          ID   subject       age
# 1 something something something
# 2         1       His        21
# 3         2       Geo        24
# 4         3       Geo        26
# 5         4       His        23
# 6         5       Geo        26
```

R's [`rbind`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/main/bind.c) already cares for this in C language, which is fast, and we don't need to `Map` over anything;

```
rbind(c("something", NA, NA), mydata)
```

to avoid endless typing of `NA` we may thus use the proposed solution:

```
rbind(`length<-`("School 1", ncol(mydata)), mydata)
#          ID subject  age
# 1 something    <NA> <NA>
# 2         1     His   21
# 3         2     Geo   24
# 4         3     Geo   26
# 5         4     His   23
# 6         5     Geo   26
```